# Jquery Autocomplete is not working in a redirected page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete textbox in partial view which is working fine when referred from lets say on View 1.On view 1 i have a button ,on click of which i am redirecting to view 2 which also refers this partial view.But here on view 2 ,autocomplete is not working.

```
 $("#ImportEligibilityCode").click(function () {
                window.location.href('@Url.Action("ImportEligibilityCode", "UploadEligibilityCodes")');

        });
```

"ImportEligibilityCode" action of controller "UploadEligibilityCodes" returns  a partial view which contains the Autocomplete textbox.
Searched and tried lots of options from internet but its not solved yet.Pls help :)

Comment: You are treating href as if it were a function, its not. try something like window.location.href ='@Url.Action("ImportEligibilityCode", "UploadEligibilityCodes")';

Comment: I changed the call as told by you.But this does not affect jquery autocomplete at all.No luck.Its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Autocomplete and various other jQuery methods to work on elements that have been loaded via AJAX after the initial page load, then you need to wrap them in the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function instead of doing it the typical way. Below is an example for how to call jQuery Autocomplete in a way that works on elements that have been loaded via AJAX. Simply replace the CSS selector / Controller/Action and item/value with appropriate values for your page.

```
<script>
    $('body').on('keydown.autocomplete', '.your-css-selector', function () {

        $(".your-css-selector").autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Controller/AutoCompleteAction",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.description, value: item.value };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have got into another issue with this. I have multiple textboxes on my page which has autocomplete functionality and needs different function call to get the populate list. I have written the ajax code to populate the textboxes in separate functions and calling them like this :  $('body').on('keydown.autocomplete', '#txtPlanName', PlanNameAutoComplete); and $('body').on('keydown.autocomplete', '#txtProductName', ProductNameAutoComplete); But in this case only PlanName textbox is working fine and not the product name textbox.How can i handle this.